# require.js order plugin and define

Tags: requirejs, amd

How does define() treat traditional javascript files?

For example,

a.js

```
define(['b', 'c.js', 'd.js'], function(b){ /* code */});
```

When does c.js or d.js get fetched and loaded?  Will it be loaded and available in function(b){}?

I know that the order is not preserved.  Will the order plugin help for this?
The docs say

> It is not needed for scripts that use define() to define modules

but does that apply to traditional scripts as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain Javascript files that do not define modules, they will be loaded and executed in arbitrary order.  In your example above, there's no guarantee that `c.js` will execute before `d.js`.  But by the time your callback executes, both will be loaded.

If you need `c.js` and `d.js` to execute in order, use the order plugin.